# How to get first character of string?

Tags: javascript

I have a string, and I need to get its first character.

```js
var x = 'somestring';
alert(x[0]); //in ie7 returns undefined
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: just be careful - you might not have a character there to extract!

Answer (score 1295, accepted):

`charAt` can give wrong results for Unicode. Use `Array.from`:

```js
Array.from('some string')[0];
```

Comment: Worked on IE7, Chrome, Firefox.

Comment: `x.charAt()` will also return the first character as if no index is passed to this method, it will assume it to the `0`.

Comment: @MohammadUsman While what you say is true, unfortunately charAt() without any parameters actually runs about 10x slower than chartAt(0) in Firefox as of Firefox 71. See for yourself here: https://jsperf.com/testing-the-first-character-in-a-string/1

Comment: This solution is good for ASCII, but it will break in all sorts of way as soon as you deal with more than that.  `"".charAt(0)` returns `"\ud83d"`, `"café".charAt(3)` returns `e` and drops the accent, etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345372/why-is-an-emoji-string-length-2 has some info and a good alternative (use a library)

Comment: Also, to avoid confusion for future visitors: `x[0]` works just as well as `x.charAt(0)`, unless you care about IE 7

Comment: @Clément Interesting your `é` is different than what you'd get on a keyboard, it is actually an e on the first code byte and just an accent on the second `'é'.charCodeAt(0) === 101 && 'é'.charCodeAt(1) === 769`
`'é'.charCodeAt(0) === 233`

Comment: Not sure what you call "on a keyboard", but there's indeed a precomposed "é" in unicode that's different from "e" + combining accent.

Comment: Wow all the obscure techno-geekery. What's the best way to get a substring from a string? Are you absolutely, positively sure that there's not already a function designed to extract substrings, that understands strings, in the language, that we could be overlooking?

Answer (score 187):

In JavaScript you can do this:

```js
const x = 'some string';
console.log(x.substring(0, 1));
```

Comment: if prefer to use sub-string funcs, the `x.slice(0,1)` is shorter. And to get the last char simply use: `x.slice(-1)`

Comment: "slice" is shorter as long as you don't think it's a waste to lose a few seconds of life every time you (or any other maintainer) read it and have to think about what it's actually supposed to achieve, every time you touch the code again. Forever. Just use the function that actually says what you are doing, you'll be happier 20 years from now when you're trying to fix the mess you made. #personalexperience

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The whole "array" thing is cute and shows off casting strings to arrays and such but the question is, literally, "how do I get a one-character substring from the start of the string"; the obvious answer is to use the function called "substring". I mean. Elegance over flash.

Comment: @tekHedd "The whole 'array' thing is cute" no, the whole array thing is *correct*: basically all of the other solutions (charAt, substring, regex, bracket index) will not work as expected on non-ascii strings. Which may be *fine* for the use case at hand, but the array version will always work correctly. The other answers should *at least* mention the caveats. Although TBF it's not like the accepted answer mentions it either.

Comment: @JaredSmith No, maybe you're thinking of python 2 or C. Javascript in this decade handles multibyte code points correctly. For example: "₳℮∑┌".substring(2) returns "∑┌".

Comment: @tekHedd not necessarily, `''.substring(0, 1)` does not yield the expected '', but destructuring does.

Answer (score 130):

You can use any of these.

There is a little difference between all of these
So be careful while using it in conditional statement.

```js
var string = "hello world";
console.log(string.slice(0,1));     //o/p:- h
console.log(string.charAt(0));      //o/p:- h
console.log(string.substring(0,1)); //o/p:- h
console.log(string.substr(0,1));    //o/p:- h
console.log(string[0]);             //o/p:- h
console.log(string.at(0));          //o/p:- h


var string = "";
console.log(string.slice(0,1));     //o/p:- (an empty string)
console.log(string.charAt(0));      //o/p:- (an empty string)
console.log(string.substring(0,1)); //o/p:- (an empty string)
console.log(string.substr(0,1));    //o/p:- (an empty string)
console.log(string[0]);             //o/p:- undefined
console.log(string.at(0));          //o/p:- undefined
```

Comment: missing string.substr(0,1); :)

Comment: missing string.at(0)

Answer (score 37):

Example of all method

**First** : `string.charAt(index)`

> Return the caract at the index `index`

```js
var str = "Stack overflow";

console.log(str.charAt(0));
```

**Second** : `string.substring(start,length);`

> Return the substring in the string who start at the index `start` and stop after the length `length`

Here you only want the first caract so : `start = 0` and `length = 1`

```js
var str = "Stack overflow";

console.log(str.substring(0,1));
```

**Alternative** : `string[index]`

A string is an array of caract. So you can get the first caract like the first cell of an array.

> Return the caract at the index `index` of the string

```js
var str = "Stack overflow";

console.log(str[0]);
```

Comment: Timing a single operation using console.time() is not a reasonable or accurate test of performance. Of COURSE there is no big difference between them when you only time a single operation. These methods do actually perform differently.

Answer (score 34):

```js
const x = 'some string';
console.log(x.substring(0, 1));
```

Comment: substring is about 90% slower as charAt
see [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/jssubstrcharat)

Answer (score 18):

```
var x = "somestring"
alert(x.charAt(0));
```

The charAt() method allows you to specify the position of the character you want.

What you were trying to do is get the character at the position of an array "x", which is not defined as X is not an array.

Answer (score 16):

You can even use `slice` to cut-off all other characters:

```
x.slice(0, 1);
```

Comment: This method will be one of the least performant methods of solving this. Sub-optimal.

Answer (score 8):

```
var str="stack overflow";

firstChar  = str.charAt(0);

secondChar = str.charAt(1);
```

Tested in **IE6+**, **FF**, **Chrome**, **safari**.

Comment: just curious, is there a reason you posted this answer? It seems to be a duplicate of the accepted answer.

Comment: They did give some extra info (even if it should have been a comment)... like what browsers it was tested in.  I know `indexOf` doesn't work in IE8 and that's rather important to me.  I actually started to google charAt compatibility until I saw this answer way down here.

Answer (score 6):

Try this as well:

```
x.substr(0, 1);
```

Comment: substr() is considered a legacy function and should be avoided if at all possible. It is not actually a part of the JS language and could be removed at any time. Stay away from using substr() in all new code and old code should be refactored to use other methods. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

Answer (score 4):

Looks like I am late to the party, but try the below solution which I personally found the best solution:

```
var x = "testing sub string"
alert(x[0]);
alert(x[1]);
```

Output should show alert with below values:
"t"
"e"

Answer (score 3):

You can use any of the following :

```
let userEmail = "email";
console.log(userEmail[0]); // e
console.log(userEmail.charAt(0)); // e
console.log(userEmail.slice(0, 1)); // e
console.log(userEmail.substring(0, 1)); // e
console.log(userEmail.substr(0, 1)); // e
console.log(userEmail.split("", 1).toString()); // e
console.log(userEmail.match(/./)[0]); // e
```

Answer (score 2):

`x.substring(0,1)`

## Details

`substring(start, end)`  extracts the characters from a string, between the 2 indices "start" and "end", **not** including "end" itself.

## Special notes

- If "start" is greater than "end", this method will swap the two arguments, meaning str.substring(1, 4) == str.substring(4, 1).
- If either "start" or "end" is less than 0, it is treated as if it were 0.

Answer (score 2):

you can use in this way:

```
'Hello Mr Been'.split(' ').map( item => item.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1)).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

in Nodejs you can use Buffer :

```
let str = "hello world"
let buffer = Buffer.alloc(2, str) // replace 2 by 1 for the first char
console.log(buffer.toString('utf-8')) // display he
console.log(buffer.toString('utf-8').length) // display 2
```

Answer (score 1):

`charAt()` do not work if it has a parent prop 
ex `parent.child.chartAt(0)` 
use `parent.child.slice(0, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Since every string is an array, probably the most succinct solution is by using the new spread operator:

```
const x = 'somestring'
const [head, ...tail] = x
console.log(head) // 's'
```

bonus is you can now access the total string but the first character using `join('')` on `tail`:

```
console.log(tail.join('')) // 'omestring'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been 12 years and just one dev mentioned regexp, but it's a simpler way:

```
const str = 'string';

str.match(/\w/); // >> s
```

It will return the first character-class-word from the given string.

Comment: The JS `\w` shorthand is not unicode-aware: this will give the wrong answer for non-ascii strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's been 10 years yet no answer mentioned `RegExp`.

```js
var x = 'somestring';
console.log(x.match(/./)[0]);
```

Comment: The JS regex `.` is not unicode-aware, this will give the wrong answer for non-ascii strings.

Answer (score 0):

For any string str = "Hello World"

str.split(' ').map( item => item.toUpperCase().substring(0, 1)).join(' ');

Output: H W

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to find the string first character in Javascript. I think the easiest way to find is the string.charAt() method. This method takes an index number as a parameter and returns the index value. If you didn't give any parameter by default its returns the first character of the string.

```js
 const str = "Bangladesh";
 const firstCharacter = str.charAt(0);
 const secondCharacter = str.charAt(1);
 console.log(firstCharacter)
 console.log(secondCharacter)
```

Answer (score -1):

in JQuery you can use:
in class for Select Option:

```
$('.className').each(function(){
    className.push($("option:selected",this).val().substr(1));
});
```

in class for text Value:

```
$('.className').each(function(){
    className.push($(this).val().substr(1));
});
```

in ID for text Value:

```
$("#id").val().substr(1)
```

Comment: This gets everything *after* the first character, not the first character.

Answer (score -1):

You can use as well:

```
var x = "somestring";

console.log(x.split("")[0]); // output "s"
```

This should work with older browsers.