# I want to know how i look all the names that begin with A

Tags: javascript, string

I want to know how i look all the names that begin with A or B or something like that example i have  David Daniel Jose Alejandro and i only want that names that begin  with the A. can someone tell me.
name = start with A
Is it now clear what I need?

Comment: All the names where? In an array? What does this have to do with cookies?

Comment: In a table or something like that just i wanna know how i make a condition to look the names that begin with a specific letter

Comment: I just wrote this, now it's closed, but I will post it here anyway:


    `var names = ['Alex','James','Robert','Andrea','Samantha','Barnaby'];
    
    function getAllByLetter(list, letter) {
      x = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase() == letter.toLowerCase()) {
          x.push(list[i]);
        }
      } return x;
    }`


This is untested, but I think it should work. simply use `getAllByLetter(names,'a')`

Comment: the 'table' is full.name but i use getAllByLetter(full.name,'a') and is not working

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

[How to get first character of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427132/how-to-get-first-character-of-string)

Basically

```
if (yourstring.charAt(0) == 'A'){
  *your desired code*
}
```