# What characters are grouped with Array.from?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode, iterator

I've been playing around with JS and can't figure out how JS decides which elements to add to the created array when using `Array.from()`. For example, the following emoji  has a `length` of 2, as it is made of two code points, but, `Array.from()` treats these two code points as one, giving an array with one element:

```js
const emoji = '';
console.log(Array.from(emoji)); // Output: [""]
```

However, some other characters also have two code points such as this character `षि` (also has a `.length` of 2). However, `Array.from` doesn't "group" this character and instead produces two elements:

```js
const str = 'षि';
console.log(Array.from(str)); // Output: ["ष", "ि"]
```

My question is: What determines whether the character is broken up (like in example two) or treated as one single element (like in example one) when the character consists of two code points?

Comment: Have a look at UTF-16 surrogate pairs ...

Comment: [Why is an emoji string length 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38345372) and [How can I split a string containing emoji into an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531751) and [How to count the correct length of a string with emojis in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369513). `षि` is 2 separate characters

Comment: I have a concern about MDN's polyfill of Array.from, which has a different behavior :-s

Comment: @Ele it only considers objects with `length`. Iterators or even `Set` doesn't work with that

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Array.from` first tries to invoke the iterator of the argument if it has one, and strings do have iterators, so it invokes `String.prototype[Symbol.iterator]`, so let's look up how the prototype method works. It's described in the specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype-@@iterator):

> 1. Let O be ? RequireObjectCoercible(this value).
> 2. Let S be ? ToString(O).
> 3. Return CreateStringIterator(S).

Looking up `CreateStringIterator` eventually takes you to [`21.1.5.2.1 %StringIteratorPrototype%.next ( )`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-%stringiteratorprototype%.next), which does:

> 9. Let cp be ! CodePointAt(s, position).
> 10. Let resultString be the String value containing cp.[[CodeUnitCount]] consecutive code units from s beginning with the code unit at index position.
> 11. Set O.[[StringNextIndex]] to position + cp.[[CodeUnitCount]].
> 12. Return CreateIterResultObject(resultString, false).

The `CodeUnitCount` is what you're interested in. This number comes from [CodePointAt](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-codepointat) :

> 3. Let first be the code unit at index position within string.
> 4. Let cp be the code point whose numeric value is that of first.
> 5. If first is not a leading surrogate or trailing surrogate, then
>
>    a. Return the Record `{ [[CodePoint]]: cp, [[CodeUnitCount]]: 1, [[IsUnpairedSurrogate]]: false }`.
> 6. If first is a trailing surrogate or position + 1 = size, then
>
>    a.Return the Record `{ [[CodePoint]]: cp, [[CodeUnitCount]]: 1, [[IsUnpairedSurrogate]]: true }`.
> 7. Let second be the code unit at index position + 1 within string.
> 8. If second is not a trailing surrogate, then
>
>    a. Return the Record `{ [[CodePoint]]: cp, [[CodeUnitCount]]: 1, [[IsUnpairedSurrogate]]: true }`.
> 9. Set cp to ! UTF16DecodeSurrogatePair(first, second).
> 10. Return the Record `{ [[CodePoint]]: cp, [[CodeUnitCount]]: 2, [[IsUnpairedSurrogate]]: false }`.

So, when iterating over a string with `Array.from`, it returns a CodeUnitCount of 2 only when the character in question is the start of a surrogate pair. Characters that are interpreted as surrogate pairs are described [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#leading-surrogate):

> Such operations apply special treatment to every code unit with a numeric value in the inclusive range **0xD800 to 0xDBFF** (defined by the Unicode Standard as a **leading surrogate**, or more formally as a high-surrogate code unit) and every code unit with a numeric value in the inclusive range 0xDC00 to 0xDFFF (defined as a trailing surrogate, or more formally as a low-surrogate code unit) using the following rules..:

`षि` is not a surrogate pair:

```js
console.log('षि'.charCodeAt()); // First character code: 2359, or 0x937
console.log('षि'.charCodeAt(1)); // Second character code: 2367, or 0x93F
```

But 's characters are:

```js
console.log(''.charCodeAt()); // 55357, or 0xD83D
console.log(''.charCodeAt(1)); // 56397, or 0xDC4D
```

The first character code of `''` is, in hex, D83D, which is within the range of `0xD800 to 0xDBFF` of leading surrogates. In contrast, the first character code of `'षि'` is much lower, and is not. So the `'षि'` gets split apart, but `''` doesn't.

`षि` is composed of two separate characters: `ष`, [Devanagari Letter Ssa](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/2359), and `ि`, [Devanagari Vowel Sign I](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/2367). When next to each other in this order, they get graphically combined into a single character visually, despite being composed of two separate characters.

In contrast, the character codes of  *only* make sense when together as a single glyph. If you try to use a string with either code point without the other, you'll get a nonsense symbol:

```js
console.log(''[0]);
console.log(''[1]);
```

Comment: I think that, while mostly correct, useful, and with carefully provided citations, this answer fails to clearly explain the key difference between the two cases: from the Unicode point of view, `षि` is actually *two* characters with distinct code points combined to form a single glyph (one *abstract* character, as understood by humans). This is in contrast to the `` emoji, which is a complete character in and of itself, even though its code point is high enough that it has to be split into a surrogate pair. I believe clarifying that could help this (otherwise valuable) answer a lot.

Comment: Specifically, the consonant ष (ṣ) and the vowel ि (i) graphically combining into the syllable षि (ṣi)

Comment: @CertainPerformance There is only one code point in "". This suggests the terminology in this answer might be incorrect.

Answer (score 13):

UTF-16 (the encoding used for strings in js) uses 16bit units. So every unicode that can be represented using 15 bit is represented as one code point, everything else as two, known as *surrogate pairs*. The [iterator of strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) iterates over code points.

[UTF-16 on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)

Answer (score 8):

It's all about the code behind the characters. Some are coded in two bytes (UTF-16) and are interpreted by `Array.from` as two characters. Gotta check the list of the characters :

http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm

http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm

```js
function displayHexUnicode(s) {
  console.log(s.split("").reduce((hex,c)=>hex+=c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4,"0"),""));
}

displayHexUnicode('षि');

console.log(Array.from('षि').forEach(x => displayHexUnicode(x)));
```

---

```js
function displayHexUnicode(s) {
  console.log(s.split("").reduce((hex,c)=>hex+=c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).padStart(4,"0"),""));
}

displayHexUnicode('');

console.log(Array.from('').forEach(x => displayHexUnicode(x)));
```

---

For the function that displays the hex code :

[Javascript: Unicode string to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647928/javascript-unicode-string-to-hex)