# Using arrow function in javascript to return the initials of the First Name and Last Name

Tags: javascript

Trying to have console log show the initials of the first and last name when using arrow functions in javascript.

```js
const getInitials = (firstName, lastName) => {
  firstName + lastName;
}
console.log(getInitials("Charlie", "Brown"));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get first character of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427132/how-to-get-first-character-of-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get first chars from names.

```js
const getInitials = (firstName, lastName) => `${firstName[0]}${lastName[0]}`
console.log(getInitials("Charlie", "Brown"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify `return` inside the curly brackets. You can use [`charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) to get the initials:

```js
const getInitials = (firstName,lastName) => { return firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.charAt(0); }
console.log(getInitials("Charlie", "Brown"));
```

**OR:** You do not need the `return` if remove the curly brackets:

```js
const getInitials = (firstName,lastName) => firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.charAt(0);
console.log(getInitials("Charlie", "Brown"));
```

Comment: (They're also looking for initials rather than entire strings)

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning the initials, you're returning the whole name. Use `[0]` to get the first character of a string.

In an arrow function, don't put the expression in `{}` if you just want to return it as a result.

```js
const getInitials = (firstName, lastName) => firstName[0] + lastName[0];
console.log(getInitials("Charlie", "Brown"));
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give an arrow function a code block (`{}`), you need to explicitly define the `return` statement. In your example, you don't need a code block since you're only wanting to return a single value. So, you can remove the code block, and instead place the return value to the right of the arrow `=>`.

In order to get the first characters in your strings, you can use bracket notation (`[0]`) to index the string, `.charAt(0)`, or even [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like so:

```js
const getInitials = ([f],[s]) => f + s;
console.log(getInitials("Charlie", "Brown"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getInitials = (firstName,lastName) => { return firstName.charAt(0) + lastName.charAt(0); }
console.log(getInitials("Charlie", "Brown"));
```

Comment: While this answer might solve the issue, please include some additional explanatory text to assist readers understand what it is doing.